# Security-SSP "The Software Protection service has completed licensing status check." Running 12 Times an Hour

Tags: windows, services, reboot, license, windows-server-2016

It's to my understanding this should be running every 7 days or so but on our server once an hour (1:22, 2:22, 3:22...) it runs:

-The software protection service is starting

-Initilization status for service objects.....

-The Software Protection service has completed licensing status check.

-The software protection service has started.

-The Software Protection service has completed licensing status check. (six more times here)

-Successfully scheduled Software Protection service for re-start at 2119-04-29T19:21:23Z. Reason: RulesEngine. (keep in mind that's 100 years in the future)

-The Software Protection service has stopped.

System specs:
Intel Xeon 1230 V5
Windows server essentials 2016
16 gigs KVR24E17D8/16 kingston RAM
250W single power supply

This has been happening as far back as the logs go (2 months). Our server has been restarting randomly since january and it always restarts at 1:20, 2:20, 3:20... as well so I'm thinking they may be tied.

Been troubleshooting the restarts for 2 weeks now, would greatly appreciate any insight on the Software Protection Service occurrences or the restarts. It always restarts with no BSOD even though it's enabled, never does the minidump or a kernel dump and these Security-SSP events in the Application event logs are the only the only events i can find related to it.

Comment: quick update, if i change the scheduled time for the service running it (SvcRestartTask) it keeps running at the previously mentioned times and if i disable it when it gets to the time to run it something automatically re-enables it